# How to append data from a column in one worksheet to the bottom row in another

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I couldn't find anything that matches my criteria. So i'm sorry if I missed something.

I'm trying to figure out how to take several values in specific cells in one worksheet. We'll call them:

**Sheet1**

```
Range("C5")

Range("C10")

Range("C15")

Range("C20")
```

and want to write a Sub that will place those 4 values in the next available row on Sheet2, with a time stamp in the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `end(xlup)` to track the last row, e.g.:

```
dim lTargetRow as long

lTargetRow=sheets("Sheet2").cells(rows.count,2).end(xlup).row+1 'find first available row

sheets("Sheet2").cells(ltargetrow,2)=sheets("Sheet1").range("C5").value
sheets("Sheet2").cells(ltargetrow,1)=now() 'add time stamp
```

Comment: The appending worked well! And it added the data but with an error #REF. If the Range("C5") is a reference like Range("H2")/Sheet3("D2") how do I fix that?

Comment: edited code to transfer values rather than standard copy / paste

Comment: Your fix worked! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    n = s2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    k = 2
    For i = 5 To 20 Step 5
        s1.Cells(i, "C").Copy s2.Cells(n, k)
        k = k + 1
    Next i
    s2.Cells(n, 1) = Now
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Yours worked as well it. I picked bad examples because they're not actually separated by 5 each time. But that was a good move. I'm still having the #REF error because the Cells(i, "C") is a reference already...